# Choose File Download Save Path

Tags: php, browser, download

I have a list of files. A list of links with the href set to the file location.

My users click on one of the links to download the file.

My users are not tech-savvy and I like them to download the files straight to the required place.

They do this by right-clicking and select 'save link as' - then they can choose where to download to rather than the file going to the downloads folder.

I want users to be able to select multiple files to download (using checkboxes and putting in a download button). This way they click the download button and the collection of files goes to the downloads folder.

Is it possible to let users select multiple files with my checkboxes and then somehow let them choose the save location? NOT by typing in the path into an input (my users are not tech-savvy) but by triggering the browsers function of being able to click 'save link as'? Possibly using JS?

And it must be downloaded as separate files - NOT in a zip

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can return one file per request but with js you can send multiple requests.
The option to save all files to a default download folder can be set in the browser of your users, there is no way to do that via script.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['file'])) {
    header("Content-transfer-encodig: binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($_REQUEST['file']) );
    readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'//path//to//' . $_REQUEST['file'] );
    exit;
}
?>

<input type="checkbox" class="files" id="file1"><label for="file1">file1.txt</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="files" id="file2"><label for="file2">file2.txt</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="files" id="file3"><label for="file3">file3.txt</label>

<button onclick="downloadFiles()">Download file(s)</button>

<script>
function downloadFiles() {
    var fileIds = $('.files:checked').each(function() {
        window.open('test3.php?file=' + $(this).next('label').text());
    });
}
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```